# Podcast Speed on iPhone

Tags: iphone, podcasts.app, tweaks

How do I slow the speed of podcasts on my iPhone?

I have looked through all of my settings and have searched all possibilities on the podcast itself. Voices are too fast to be understood. There is no trouble with the playback of music.

Answer (score 2):

Yes - you can slow down podcasts by pressing the `1x` button to the left of the rewind by 15 seconds button:

[image: A podcast playing in iOS 10.]

In the above screenshot I have pressed the `1x` button until it has become `½ x` button.

If the voices are "too fast to be understood," then you may have actually **increased the playback speed** (`2x` or `3x`), and may want it back at `1x`. Either that or their voices are actually that fast and you will want to **slow it down**.

Comment: Thanks so much! My podcast have been playing too quick and it was driving me crazy!